# Selecting elements from an array and putting it in another array in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array containing 10 numbers. I want to pick numbers in array index 0,2,4,6,8 and put them in a new array. Likewise with index 1,3,5,7,9. I am new to Perl (started a few days ago).

My program:

```
my @b;
@a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
for($i=0;$i<=$#a;$i++)
   {
    push(@b,$a[$i+1]);
   }
print "@b";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Use the pragmas `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These will catch a lot of errors. If you use `use strict;`, you'll have to declare your variables with `my` (sometimes you'll use `our`, but 99% of the time, you'll use `my`)
- In your `for` loop, you're using the default variable `$_`. This variable is evil for a variety of reasons. (One, it's global in scope, so something else could change this variable on your and  you wouldn't know.). Declare your variables except in situations where you must use `$_`.
- Standard is to put the `{` on the line with the `for` and `while`. Another is to avoid the `C style` for loop (and to avoid `foreach` which is just an alias to `for`)
- Use spaces. It's much easier to read `$i <= $#a` than `$i<=$a`.

Here's my interpretation of your program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);  #A nicer 'print'

my @a = qw(12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20);
my @even;
my @odd;

for my $element (0..$#a) {
if ( $element % 2 ) {
    push @odd, $a[$element];
}
else {
    push @even, $a[$element];
}
}
say '@even = ' . join ': ', @even;
say '@odd = ' . join ': ', @odd;
```

The output:

```
@even = 12: 14: 16: 18: 20
@odd = 13: 15: 17: 19
```

- Note my `for` loop. I use the `0..$#a` to go through each element of the array. The `$#` is returns the last index of the array. Note that this is easier to understand than the `for($i=0;$i<=$#a;$i++)` that you used. It's one of the reasons why C style for loops are discouraged.
- I use the modulo operator `%` to parse my even/odd. Modulo is like remainder division. If the number is odd, the modulo `% 2` will be a 1. Otherwise, it's zero. Modulo operations are great for anything that works on a cycle.

---

But let's get back to your program. Here's your original code with a few minor tweaks.

- I added the `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. These catch about 99% of your programming errors.
- I use `use feature qw(say);` because `say` is nicer when it comes to debugging. I can take a statement, copy it, and then throw say `qq(...);` around it and see what it's doing.
- I added a bunch of `say` statements to reveal the logic of your code.

Let's watch what happens. Here's your program slightly modified:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @b;
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
my $i;
for($i=0; $i<=$#a; $i++) {
    say "Index = $i  Element = $a[$i + 1]";
    say qq(push(\@b, $a[$i+1]););
    push(@b,$a[$i+1]);
}
print "@b";
```

And here's the output:

```
Index = 0  Element = 2
push(@b, 2);
Index = 1  Element = 3
push(@b, 3);
Index = 2  Element = 4
push(@b, 4);
Index = 3  Element = 5
push(@b, 5);
Index = 4  Element = 6
push(@b, 6);
Index = 5  Element = 7
push(@b, 7);
Index = 6  Element = 8
push(@b, 8);
Index = 7  Element = 9
push(@b, 9);
Index = 8  Element = 10
push(@b, 10);
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 11.
Index = 9  Element = 
Use of uninitialized value within @a in concatenation (.) or string at ./test.pl line 12.
push(@b, );
Use of uninitialized value $b[9] in join or string at ./test.pl line 15.
```

I can see the how each `push` statement is being executed, and look at that, you're pushing in each and every element. Actually, you're not because you used `$a[$i+1]` as what you're pushing.

Using `use warnings` and I can see that I am trying to push the non-existant `$a[10]` into your `@b` array.

Let's change your `for` loop to go to *every other* element

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @b;
my @a = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10);
my $i;
for ($i=0; $i <= $#a; $i += 2) {
    push @b, $a[$i];
}
```

The first element is `$a[0]`. The next element in the loop is `$a[2]` because I added `2` to the index instead of just incrementing it by `1`. Now, I'll go through all the even elements and skip all of the odd elements.

And the output:

```
1 3 5 7 9
```

(Note that $a[0] = 1. That's why they're all odd numbers. It's why I started at `12` in my program, so $a[0] = 12 which is the even number).

My preference would be to use the `while` and avoid the `for(...; ...; ...)` construct:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

my @b;
my @a = qw(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10);
my $i = 0;
while ( $i < $#a ) {
    push @b, $a[$i];
    $i += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest avoiding `for` loop as it's easier to make mistake somewhere in its usage, and use `foreach`

```
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

my (@even, @odd);
foreach my $i (0 .. $#a) {

  if ($i % 2) { push @odd, $a[$i] } else { push @even, $a[$i] }
}
```

You can also use `map` to test array index modulo `%` 2, and then for `@even` decide to filter it by `()` or take value for it using `$a[$_]`

```
my @even = map { $_%2 ? () : $a[$_] } 0 .. $#a;
my @odd = map {  $_%2 ? $a[$_] : () } 0 .. $#a;
```

Comment: He wants the even _indexes_, not the even values.

Comment: Actually, he wants the values from the even indexes.

Comment: Correct, I want values from even indexes. Sorry for the unclear question.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.

```
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

my (@even, @odd);

for ( @a ) {
   $_ % 2 ? push @odd, $_ : push @even, $_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even:

```
for($i=0;$i<=$#a;$i+=2)
   {
    push(@b,$a[$i]);
   }
```

Odd:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$#a;$i+=2)
   {
    push(@b,$a[$i]);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils) has an `indexes` function:

```
use List::MoreUtils qw{indexes} ;
use 5.10.0 ;                                              
my @a = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) ; 

# index of array where even
say foreach indexes { $_ % 2 == 0 } @a ;

# index of array where odd
say foreach indexes { $_ % 2 != 0 } @a ;
```

I admit this may be sort of inelegant and it's possibly cheating here to use a module - especially one that is not in CORE.  It would be convenient if `List::MoreUtils`  and `List::Utils` were just one CORE module, but still not as elegant as some the other answers here.